# Textbox and Class

Tags: vb.net

Have trouble connecting exception to textbox input - Program should only accept "IL", "MO" or "WI" - But it's accepting every input.  Everything I tried I'm hitting a brick wall - I know the solution is there, I just need some help.  Thanks

***Form Codes***

Public Class Form1

```
Dim packages(4) As Packages
Dim pkg As Integer = 0

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    packages(0) = New Packages("Z111", "Eau Claire", "WI")
    packages(1) = New Packages("Z121", "Vicki Vale", "IL")
    packages(2) = New Packages("Z131", "Sammy Davis", "MO")
    packages(3) = New Packages("Z141", "Jon Smith", "IL")
    packages(4) = New Packages("Z151", "Suzie Cassidy", "WI")

    DisplayInfo()

End Sub

Sub DisplayInfo()

    txtID.Text = packages(pkg).PackageID
    txtCity.Text = packages(pkg).DestinationCity
    txtState.Text = packages(pkg).DestinationState
    lblPackageCount.Text = "Package #   " & pkg + 1

End Sub

Private Sub btnFirst_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFirst.Click
    pkg = 0
    DisplayInfo()
End Sub

Private Sub btnPrevious_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrevious.Click
    If pkg > 0 Then
        pkg -= 1
        DisplayInfo()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
    If pkg < packages.Length - 1 Then
        pkg += 1
        DisplayInfo()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnLast_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLast.Click
    pkg = packages.Length - 1
    DisplayInfo()
End Sub

Private Sub btnSaveChanges_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveChanges.Click

    Try

        packages(pkg).PackageID = txtID.Text
        packages(pkg).DestinationCity = txtCity.Text
        packages(pkg).DestinationState = txtState.Text

    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try

End Sub
```

End Class

***Class Codes***

Public Class Packages

```
Private packID As String
Private desCity As String
Private desState As String

Sub New(id As String, city As String, state As String)
    packID = id
    desCity = city
    desState = state
End Sub

Public Property PackageID As String
    Get
        Return packID
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        packID = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property DestinationCity As String
    Get
        Return desCity
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        desCity = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property DestinationState As String
    Get
        Return desState
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        If desState = "IL" Then
            desState = value
        ElseIf desState = "WI" Then
            desState = value
        ElseIf desState = "MO" Then
            desState = value
        Else
            Throw New Exception("Can not deliver to this state")
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

End Class

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "accepting every input". I see that once you click "btnSaveChanges" and your "txtState" will have "PA", you should have a messege box

Comment: If I input AZ in to the State textbox it's posting it into the array, it's not throwing exception.

Comment: you may just put a break point at the setter of DestinationState property and find out what the value is being set here - it could be something odd... from there you could drill down to the cause.

Comment: I did all that - that's why I'm seeking help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate problem is you're checking the property value instead of the passed value.  Something like this should work:

```
Set(value As String)
    'This creates a temporary string array of available states and checks if _
     the value passed is contained in the array
    If {"IL","WI", "MO"}.Contains(value)Then
        desState = value
    Else
        Throw New Exception("Can not deliver to this state")
    End If
End Set
```

If this is something you may need to change you could make the array a property.

Comment: Thank you very much tinstaafl - Didn't know why I didn't think of that.